# Assume it is decided to design a two dimensional 512 byte (byte addressable) RAM from 16 byte chips

Tags: architecture, organization

Assume it is decided to design a two dimensional 512 byte (byte addressable) RAM from 16 byte chips. Each of the 16 byte chips has two select-lines. The chip is enabled only if both of the select-lines are activated. Your design must use only decoders of size 3 X 8 and 2 X 4. Need to show the components, the connections and size of each component!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [electronics.se], but the question will require work before it's acceptable there.

Comment: On  Electrical Engineering @HoboSapiens https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175845/two-dimensional-512-byte-byte-addressable-ram-from-16-byte-chips

Answer (score 0):

I reposted and answered the question on the Electrical Engineering: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175845/two-dimensional-512-byte-byte-addressable-ram-from-16-byte-chips/177355#177355